# How to forward urls without ports from one machine to urls with ports on another machine

Tags: url, forwarding, ports, node.js

I'm new to sys administration, so I play some things virtually at home.

And so, I have one virtual linux with two nodejs applications running there. They listen on two different ports. Lets call the machine "node".

So, I want to make the other virtual linux to accept two different domain requests, and forward them to the two nodejs applications on "node".

Let say:

domain-one.local   ===>    [node's IP]:8080

domain-two.local   ===>    [node's IP]:8020

So, can you guide me? ... or tell me where I can find the answer? ... cause I have experience (some ... not very big) at installing, updating, configuring ... but for such things ... I just don't have any idea how to make :) ...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

One way can be to use nginx as a reverse proxy on the host machine.

You will need to use 2 server directives. one for each domain.

In case you havent used nginx before, You can refer this

http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766288369/using-nginx-reverse-proxy

This can also be helpful.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html